# Change Angular Timepicker font size

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm using the [angular bootstrap timepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker) but I cannot seem to change the font size which cuts off some of the text like below:

[image: Timepicker]

HTML:

```
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label>End:</label>
                <timepicker ng-model="filter_endtime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" 
                    minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I inspect the element in a browser I can change the .form-control font-size to 12px and it looks fine.

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4285;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

#### Is there anyway I can override the font size in the timepicker control?

I've tried doing

```
font-size: 12px !important;
```

as another class in the input-group but it makes it look like this:

[image: time2]

Comment: Do you any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: use font-size in .form-control class in your styles.

Answer (score 0):

change .form-control class styles in your bootstrap css.

```
.form-control{
font-size:12px
}
```

or use inline style

```
<timepicker style="font-size:12px;" ng-model="filter_endtime" ng-change="changed()" 
hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian">
</timepicker>
```

Comment: The angular directive timepicker cannot have a style applied inline. It overwrites it by replacing the timepicker as a table. Setting .form-control to 12px in the stylesheet would make every control 12px which I don't want

Comment: have you another style? add the .form-control{font-size:12px;} to your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Just set css for .bootstrap-timepicker-hour and .bootstrap-timepicker-minute:

```
bootstrap-timepicker-hour{
font-size:12px !important;
}
```

Try in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sqe64a09/

Comment: Can you do without the !important flag?

Comment: Redifine styles like .bootstrap-timepicker-widget .bootstrap-timepicker-hour{
font-size:12px;
} Read more http://www.thebrightlines.com/2012/02/22/a-better-alternative-to-important/